# Inserting values from an XML file to MySql:

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have the following file hosted on a remote server, I want to add the values inside this file to Mysql tables. There are four tables in all.

Below are the contents of the file. I tried to construct a Name Value pair PHP array but I am stuck as to how to insert the values.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <database name='anahuacForm'>
             <table name='Details'>
              <row>
                <col name='_id'>1</col>
                <col name='IDno'>Ggvbbvhh</col>
                <col name='GIDno'>Vvb</col>
                <col name='Name'>Bnb</col>
                <col name='Owner'></col>
                <col name='Breed'>Marwari horse</col>
                <col name='Gender'>Gender</col>
                <col name='Date'>16-May-2013</col>
                <col name='Notes'></col>
                <col name='Nature'>Nature</col>
                <col name='Color'>Color</col>
                <col name='Sire'></col>
                <col name='Dam'></col>
                <col name='Height'>0.0hh</col>
                <col name='Foaled'></col>
                <col name='Acquired'>16-May-2013</col>
                <col name='image'>null</col>
            </row>
        </table>
        <table name='Vaccination'>
            <row>
                <col name='_id'>1</col>
                <col name='flag'>Pending</col>
                <col name='HVID'>Ggvbbvhh</col>
                <col name='Vname'>Rabies</col>
                <col name='Vdate'>16-5-2013 </col>
                <col name='Vtime'>17:22</col>
            </row>
        </table>
        <table name='DeWorming'>
            <row>
                <col name='_id'>1</col>
                <col name='flag'>Pending</col>
                <col name='DVID'>Ggvbbvhh</col>
                <col name='Dname'>Large strongyles</col>
                <col name='Ddate'>16-5-2013 </col>
                <col name='Dtime'>17:22</col>
            </row>
        </table>
        <table name='Weight'>
            <row>
                <col name='_id'>1</col>
                <col name='HWID'>Ggvbbvhh</col>
                <col name='Wmeasure'> 32.27lbs</col>
                <col name='WDate'>2013-05-16</col>
            </row>
        </table>
   </database>
```

Comment: Take a look at this, it should help you out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-xml.html

Comment: have a read of this
http://php.net/manual/en/function.xm...nto-struct.php
look at example 3 it will turn your XML into a array that you could then use to create your database query's to insert it

Comment: I tried the first link but I am not getting it. The second link is not found.

Comment: try this link http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_tree.asp

Comment: Are you trying to learn how to connect to a mysql database?  Do you already have a connection?  Do you just need the SQL syntax to insert rows?  Have you read the mysql docs or the PHP docs?

Comment: It's all set, I just need to extract the values. I am actually backing up a DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code i have tried it for the table Vaccination

```
<?php
    $slideids = array();
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->load('test.xml'); // path of your XML file ,make sure path is correct
    $xpd = new DOMXPath($xml);
    false&&$result_data = new DOMElement(); //this is for my IDE to have intellysense
    $result = $xpd->query("//database/table[@name='Vaccination']/row/*");  // change the table name here
    foreach($result as $result_data){
        $key = $result_data->getAttribute('name');
        $values = $result_data->nodeValue;
        $slideids[$key] = $values;
    }

    echo $sql = "INSERT INTO Vaccination (_id, flag, HVID, Vname, Vdate, Vtime)
      VALUES ('".$slideids['_id']."','".$slideids['flag']."','".$slideids['HVID']."','".$slideids['Vname']."','".$slideids['Vdate']."','".$slideids['Vtime']."')";

?>
```

output is

```
 INSERT INTO Vaccination (_id, flag, HVID, Vname, Vdate, Vtime) 
     VALUES ('1','Pending','Ggvbbvhh','Rabies','16-5-2013 ','17:22')
```

Comment: You are the saviour! Man takes a bow :)

Comment: How do I modify this code if I have two <row> nodes inside a table, that is if I have two rows in Details or any other table? Can you give me an idea? As of now only the last row is updated in the query.

Comment: for more than one `row` you have to use `array_push` in `$slideids` remember use it with key and value

Comment: Can you please give me a one line example?

Comment: @Heretic - I think M.I.T. has been far too helpful already, and you'll find it harder to learn if everyone does "examples" (i.e. your work) for you. Try something, it really will benefit you!

Comment: Actually I am not into PHP mate, help will be highly regarded :)